# Why isn't my variable available globally in Javascript / Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I'm trying to declare a global variable called `GlobalVarTest`, which is defined in a function within my function `LikeTermsCombiner2()`. In the code below, `.ReplaceThis` gets replaced successfully, as it appears within the same function in which the variable is defined, but `.ReplaceThis2` does not get replaced outside of the function.

I noted in the code where I've also tried to declare `GlobalVarTest`.

My actual code is rather long, but I whittled it down to the bare bones so that it's clear where all of the functions are. (In other words, some functions appear not to do anything in this code, but they serve a purpose in the actual code.)

```
var GlobalVarTest;

function LikeTermsCombiner2() {


   //var GlobalVarTest; Tried putting this here

  $(function() { 

   //var GlobalVarTest; Also tried putting this here

    $(function() { 

        GlobalVarTest = "5";  
        $(".ReplaceThis").html(GlobalVarTest);      

    });  

   $(".ReplaceThis2").html(GlobalVarTest);      


    });

}


$('.Expression').each(function() {

  console.log(LikeTermsCombiner2());

 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2x7049bs/162/

Comment: Using `$(function() { ... }` in a function is often suspicious, but chaining them is a whole new level of weird :) Why would you do that? Anyway, here, the second one is executed after the first one was done. You're basically adding a new handler to the document ready event, so it'll get executed when the first one is over.

Comment: The actual code is 15k lines long so it's rather complicated ha...still learning here, so I'm not surprised this isn't ideal. Is there any way to tweak the current structure or modify the `$(function() { ... }` so that I can accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: What's the purpose on the second `$(function() { ... }` exactly? Because it basically just says "do this after". So you can either remove it (just put its code directly), or define `GlobalVarTest` in the (enclosing) first one.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

You can move your embdedded function into a separate function and return a variable, assigning this to something within the first function. This does not need to be used, but will ensure the first function waits for the second to complete before continuing. As demonstrated below, this means that the global value is no longer undefined.

Please see the demo below for a working example.

---

## Explaination

```
$(function() { ... }
```

The code above is short hand for making a function run on window load, the issue you is that although you are assigning them in various locations, that does not mean the will be completed in that order.

Moving the `$(".ReplaceThis2").html(GlobalVarTest);` to after the closing tag of `function LikeTermsCombiner2() { ... }` will still not necessarily work. That function effectively adds a function to the run list after page load, but does not wait for it to be run (this function then adds a second to the run list, but again does not wait for it to be completed).

Adding a function to the run list is a much quicker action than actually processing that entire element of code so the 'parent' function races ahead without variables being defined.

---

## Demo

```js
var GlobalVarTest;

function LikeTermsCombiner2() {


  //var GlobalVarTest;

  $(function() {

    // Move current code into a separate function.
    // Call the separate function and assign to variable to ensure function waits for result 
    waitForComplete = setGlobalFn();
  
    $(".ReplaceThis2").html(GlobalVarTest);


  });

  return "LikeTermsCombiner2 return value";

}


// Bring the code that sets GlobalVarTest into a different function
function setGlobalFn() {

  // Your code...

  // Set GlobalVarTest
  GlobalVarTest = "5";

  // Replace as needed
  $(".ReplaceThis").html(GlobalVarTest);

  // Return a value (does not need to be used)
  return true;

}


$('.Expression').each(function() {

  console.log(LikeTermsCombiner2());

});
```

```css
.root {
  border-top: thin black solid;
}

.root>sup {
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.4em;
  font-size: 70%;
}

.Index {
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.4em;
  font-size: 70%;
}

.index {
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.4em;
  font-size: 70%;
}

span[class*='variable'] <span class="Parentheses FirstSet">(<span class="TermWrapper"><span class="Coefficient">1</span></span>) </span><span class="Parentheses SecondSet">(
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Expression"></span>
<br> This should say five: <span class="ReplaceThis"></span>
<br> This should also say five: <span class="ReplaceThis2"></span>
```

Comment: This makes sense, and I appreciate the thorough explanation. It works on my simplified code, but, unfortunately, when I tried to do this with the full code, it no longer runs properly. oy

Comment: It should work really... I wonder if you may have inadvertently not copied the internal function properly? 15,000 lines of code always makes life a little more tricky! If it's all fine then perhaps I'm missing something and one of the pros can explain what's going wrong / a better solution...

Comment: Instead of creating a local variable (which seems nearly impossible with my convoluted code), I've been playing with some potential work-arounds. I tried grabbing the text from the `.ReplaceThis` span and showing it in an alert...but that's not working either. The alert is generated AFTER the span's text is replaced...so do happen to have any ideas as to why it still won't it grab the text? http://jsfiddle.net/2x7049bs/172/